# Why is JS saying this function is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand what's going on here... I'm working on this project that uses Google Maps with the address auto complete. There is a call back `place_changed` for when the user selects the address that triggers a `onPlaceChanged()` method.

The problem is that inside that method I can't call any other method, it gives this error:

> TypeError: this.er is not a function

But the function exists.

```
class MyMap {
   constructor() { }
   maps() {
      autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
         document.getElementById('city-name'),
         { types: [ 'geocode' ] } );

      autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', this.onPlaceChanged);
   }

   onPlaceChanged() {
      this.er();
   }

   er() {
      console.log('please call me');
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't place everything under the constructor, but in the class instead.

Comment: You have to bind each function to the class. [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) might help.

Comment: Put the functions inside the class, not inside the constructor.

Comment: The functions are in the class, it's just misaligned.

Comment: `this.er()` is a custom method in MrRobot's class.

Comment: add at the beginning of the map() onPlaceChanged=this.onPlaceChanged.bind(this) and use onPlaceChanged instead of this.onPlaceChanged

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem is `this` scoping.

The `Autocomplete` calls your `onPlaceChanged` function, but probably doesn't set the scope on it, since you haven't told `Autocomplete` which scope you want.

You can fix this with:

```
autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', this.onPlaceChanged.bind(this));
```

This will produce a new function that automatically bind `this` as the scope before calling your original `onPlaceChanged` function.

Answer (score 2):

The code calling your callback has no idea about the execution context (the `this`), and thus calls your 'method' as a function, with `window` or `undefined` as `this`.

You can solve this by *binding* the callback to the context with `this.onPlaceChanged.bind(this)` in the `addListener` call.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this for more information.